# Which (of the Germanic) languages support resultative constructions?

Tags: syntax, semantics, cross-linguistic, list-of-languages, germanic-languages

my question regards resultative constructions. Which of the Germanic languages supports resultative constructions?
It would be awesome if you could suggest any literature regarding any language. Although this question focusses mainly on the Germanic languages, I also would be happy to hear from non-Germanic languages. I know of German, and English (and also found literature regarding that).
Examples are:

German: *Sie streicht die Tür schwarz.*

English: *She slices the cheese to pieces.*

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe there are any Germanic languages that _don’t_ allow such constructions? At a rough guess, I’d guess that most languages in the world support resultatives in one way or another (Chinese languages in particular make extreme use of them – if you read an average Mandarin Facebook post, you’ll likely see one in nearly every sentence).

Comment: I don't have any reasons why some Germanic languages wouldn't allow them. So far I'm at the very beginning of my research and am interested in some positive evidence and literature that give (language specific) overviews over phenomena of resultative secondary predication.